# How to create custom 3D Box with Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, 3d, textures

I need to create an `3D box` which the user can turn around and see all sides... The box should have `custom images on each side` which I can define.

Example:
[image]

`I want to set different images for every side of the cube`...

I hope it was clear what I want to achieve.

How to realize that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is currently possible.

[official docs faq](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#can-i-build-3d-opengl-apps-with-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package it is very good. but you would have to have the 3d model ready

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cube